# OpenCL/OpenGL Interop dimensions of a renderbuffer in relation to workgroup sizes

Tags: c++, opengl, interop, opencl, fbo

I'm doing some tests on OpenCL/OpenGL interop. One of them consists of creating an OpenGL FBO with an attached renderbuffer. I'm trying to write pixels to an associated OpenCL memory object (a image2d_t) in a kernel, keeping everything on the GPU and blitting the FBO to the main OpenGL framebuffer every frame. The framebuffer is shown in a resizable window so the size of the renderbuffer can vary.

If I try to run the kernel I get a CL_INVALID_WORKGROUP_SIZE size error unless the width and height dimensions are multiples of the (local) workgroup sizes.

Is this really necessary? I don't like having to pad extra memory, introduce width/height parameters and add additional boundary checks inside the kernel if I can avoid it...
I also wouldn't like to only use workgroup sizes of 1 ;-)

Comment: Do you need that specific local size? Or does your kernel support any local size? In the latter case, do not specify any size and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is specified in the OpenCL specification, up to 1.2, that the global size shall be a multiple of the local size. In 2.0 they relaxed this, but of course there are no 2.0 implementations yet.

The common workaround is to round-up your global work size to the next multiple of the local work size, but pass in the desired (real) global size as parameters, and then in your kernel check if global_id(0)/global_id(1) are less than the real size before doing work.

Alternative, pass NULL as your local work size and let the runtime select (but a tuned-for-the-hardware local work size is usually faster).